# I need a query which returns users who either like the comment of post or not

Tags: php, laravel

I can get the result of the users like this post or not but how can I get users who like the comment or not.

```
$posts = Post::select('id','title','slug','content','type','views','likes','shares','comments_count','followers','helpful_count','is_anonymously','user_id','created_at')
      ->with('user')
      ->with(['like' => function ($like) use ($user_id) {
      return $like->whereHas('user', function ($user) use ($user_id) {
            $user->where('id', $user_id);
            })->get();}])
      ->with('comments')
      ->where('is_spam',0)
      ->where('is_approved',1)
      ->where('group_id', $subgroup->id)
      ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
      ->paginate(3);
  return $posts;
```

The post model function is below

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comment','post_id')
            ->where('parent_id',0)
            ->with('user','subComments','like')
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc');
}
```

in Comment Model

```
public function subComments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comment', 'parent_id')->with('user','like);
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? To get the user with all its comments?

Comment: i already get all comments with sub comments what i want is i want to get like of comment is user like it or not,

 like i getting user like post or not

Comment: I understand, how do you store the likes of your users?

Comment: i have a table of comments which i store comments  and i have table of comment_likes and i have relationship that comments hasmany likes

Comment: i update my questions with calling 'like' function of comment model i getting users who like comment but i  only want to get the login user if he like it or not